# Optimising slow SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I am having problem with changing SQL query to preform faster. I need to retrieve the first and the last row for specific time interval. For example I am looking for first and last date that is in the database for some specific time interval (1h, 24h). I have this working sql statment, which I am executing using php:

```
$query = "
    SELECT Date, RainABS
    FROM ws3600
    WHERE Date IN (
        (
            SELECT MIN(Date)
            FROM ws3600
            WHERE Date >= '" . $timeInterval1 . "'
                AND Date <= '" . $timeInterval2 . "'
        ),
        (
            SELECT MAX(Date)
            FROM ws3600
            WHERE Date >= '" . $timeInterval1 . "'
                AND Date <= '" . $timeInterval2 . "'
        )
    )
";
```

As you can see from the query, the table name is ws3600, the parameters I am retrieving are Date and RainABS. I am using the IN operator and two inner select statments.

The problem is, that when executing it:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

It takes very long. I measured it using this code:

```
$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$starttime = $mtime;

$result = mysql_query($query);

$mtime = microtime();
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
$endtime = $mtime;
$totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime);
```

And it took on average 0.28s. The problem is that I have to execute 24 of this statments, which accumlates to 6,72s on average. I know I should have probably get rid of the inner selecet statments, but then I don't know how could I get the first and last row?

Comment: Do you have an index on Date?

Comment: No I don't have index on Date. I have primary index on id, which I do not need it this query. Are you suggesting that I create secondary B+ tree index on atribute Date to speed up the query?

Comment: @Jernej This query uses Date as a filter so I think the index would help much.

Comment: Wow, the BTREE index on Date really speeded things up. Now it takes for a certain query just 2*10^-4s from previous 0.16s using Flimzy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should speed it up, by reducing the number of queries by one.

```
SELECT Date, RainABS
FROM ws3600
JOIN (
    SELECT
        MIN(Date) AS min,
        MAX(Date) AS max
    FROM ws3600
    WHERE Date >= '" . $timeInterval1 . "'
        AND Date <= '" . $timeInterval2 . "'
) AS x ON (ws3600.Date = min OR ws3600.Date = max);
```

**EDIT:** Back by popular demand... I'm leaving my answer here, since it it is "technically" correct, however, I believe the best answer is to use a UNION of two queries, as suggested by Szocske.

Comment: Will try the other one and compare it for time that it takes to execute.

Comment: I have used your solution, which I have stated in other post that reduced from 0.28s to 0.16s on average with BTREE index on atribute Date. This broguht 0.16s on average down to 2*10^-4s on average.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it worked... I'm surprised it performs better than the UNION... but glad you found an answer nonetheless :)

Comment: @Flimzy I think there is really tiny difference between your and @Szocske solutions when index is used. The problem is that without index trying to find the max and min values is faster than sorting the table.

Comment: I also wonder if MySQL is clever enough to optimize MIN() and MAX() by using an Index. If so, my query still might be faster even with an index, although then the difference of course becomes much more negligible. Of course without an index, the JOIN back to the Date column can't be very fast...

Answer (score 4):

To get rid of inner selects with MIN or MAX, the answer is often ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Something like this:

```
SELECT Date, RainABS
FROM ws3600
WHERE Date >= '" . $timeInterval1 . "'
    AND Date <= '" . $timeInterval2 . "
ORDER BY Date ASC
LIMIT 1

UNION

SELECT Date, RainABS
FROM ws3600
WHERE Date >= '" . $timeInterval1 . "'
    AND Date <= '" . $timeInterval2 . "
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Oh, and an index on the Date field is likely to help at a slight cost increase on inserts.

Comment: @Szocske Why do you think this is faster?

Comment: I have not tried this solution yet, but there was another solution posted here a few minutes ago I think by Flimzy that is missing now:SELECT Date, RainABS
FROM ws3600
JOIN (
    SELECT
        MIN(Date) AS min,
        MAX(Date) AS max
    FROM ws3600
    WHERE Date >= '2010-09-17 02:00:00'
        AND Date <= '2010-09-18 02:00:00'
) AS x ON (ws3600.Date = min OR ws3600.Date = max)

Comment: This solution shortens from average 0.28s to 0.16s, but when running 24 queries it still takes on average 3,84s which is nonetheless considerably better than 6,72s.

Comment: @Flimzy Yeah, I was wondering too. Why did you delete your query? :)

Comment: I undeleted my answer... I thought this one was better :)

Comment: I would like to say that I tried this but it prints an error. Pasted form phpmyadmin: #1221 - Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Comment: @Jernej You need to add brackets: `(select...) UNION (select...)`

Comment: Thanks, it works now. It is a little bit slower than Flimzy solution, but not by much.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting and adding UNION :-) I'm not sure why ORDER BY with LIMIT works faster than subselect with MIN or MAX, but it quite often does in practice. Perhaps it gives more clear clues to the query optimizer on what we are looking for, and how many rows to expect in the result set.